# Search based on contents of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a command button set up, and I assigned a macro to it. I need the button to take the contents of cell `B2` and search for it in column `A` on the next sheet. Here is my code. As you can see, it's looking for the literal text that was there when I recorded the macro. How do I get that to search for whatever is entered into `B2`?

```
Sub Button3_Click()

    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use an advanced filter?  It does what you are looking for without the need of VBA.

Comment: Sounds like they have a form that the user is interacting with.

Comment: It's part of a worksheet. Basic data entry. So instead of having to make a new sheet for each form, I want to fill out a template and have the data stored on the next sheet in a "consolidated" manner. I am putting a part number into B2. That part number is in a list of thousands of part numbers on the next sheet. I want the command button to find the part number in the list for me. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill for what you need, but I've always believed in error checking as well as using complete and flexible code, so here's what you asked for, with comments:

```
Sub btnFindText()

    'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook          'Used to store and reference the ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet   'Used to store and reference the ActiveSheet (the sheet containing the button)
    Dim wsNext As Worksheet     'Used to store and reference the next sheet
    Dim rngFound As Range       'Used to find a matching cell in the next sheet, if any
    Dim rngText As Range        'Used to store and reference the cell that will contain the text
    Dim sFind As String         'Used to store and reference the text in wsActive, cell B2

    'Set variables
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsActive = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set rngText = wsActive.Range("B2")
    sFind = wsActive.Range("B2").Value

    'Perform error checking and return appropriate errors

    'Check if text to search for was provided
    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then
        rngText.Select
        MsgBox "No text provided in cell " & rngText.Address(0, 0), , "No Search Value"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if there is a sheet after the activesheet
    If wsActive.Index = wb.Sheets.Count Then
        MsgBox "There is not a sheet after this one to search on", , "Next Sheet Unavailable"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Next sheet found, set the wsNext variable and search for the text
    Set wsNext = wb.Sheets(wsActive.Index + 1)
    Set rngFound = wsNext.Columns("A").Find(sFind, , , xlWhole)

    'Check if anything was found
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        'Nothing found, return error
        MsgBox "No matches found for [" & sFind & "] within column A of " & wsNext.Name, , "No Matches"
    Else
        'Match found, prompt if user wants to go to its location
        If MsgBox("Match found for [" & sFind & "] at '" & wsNext.Name & "'!" & rngFound.Address(0, 0) & Chr(10) & "Go to cell?", vbYesNo, "Match Found") = vbYes Then
            wsNext.Activate
            rngFound.Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Additionally, you can do this with an `Inputbox` instead of using cell B2 as the text entry.  The code is mostly the same, I'm putting it here for you to compare/contrast, as well as hopefully learn how to do both methods.  Note that this method doesn't require to check if there's a next sheet, because we're not using an input cell.  It only needs to know what sheet to search on.

```
Sub btnFindText2()

    'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook          'Used to store and reference the ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsSearch As Worksheet   'Used to store and reference the worksheet that will be searched
    Dim rngFound As Range       'Used to find a matching cell in the next sheet, if any
    Dim sFind As String         'Used to get the search text from an inputbox

    'Set variables
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSearch = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")      'In your provided sample code, you searched on Sheet3. Update this to correct sheetname
    sFind = InputBox("Enter Part Number:")

    'Perform error checking and return appropriate errors

    'Check if text to search for was provided
    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    'Because we're using an inputbox, no need to use the Next Sheet stuff
    'Just need to search for the text
    Set rngFound = wsSearch.Columns("A").Find(sFind, , , xlWhole)

    'Check if anything was found
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        'Nothing found, return error
        MsgBox "No matches found for [" & sFind & "] within column A of " & wsSearch.Name, , "No Matches"
    Else
        'Match found, prompt if user wants to go to its location
        If MsgBox("Match found for [" & sFind & "] at '" & wsSearch.Name & "'!" & rngFound.Address(0, 0) & Chr(10) & "Go to cell?", vbYesNo, "Match Found") = vbYes Then
            wsSearch.Activate
            rngFound.Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

EDITS: Updated the `Inputbox` method code so that it doesn't use the wsNext portions, made minor adjustments in code for clarity, readability, and debugging.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I really appreciate the caparison.

Comment: @tophala You're very welcome. I'm finally done testing and tinkering, so it shouldn't need any more edits.  I hope it helps you learn both methods so you can do either on your own in future coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `Range("B2")` as the value for the `What` parameter. For example:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Range("B2"), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then

    Debug.Print "Found at " & r.Address

    ' If you want to activate it...
    r.Activate

End If
```

If you want to search for *values* instead of *formulas* (which is what your original macro was doing), replace `xlFormulas` with `xlValues`.